# Incorrect signature for a SchedulableContext

Tags: scheduled-apex, data-export

I'm trying to create a daily export of a .csv report on Salesforce Apex. 
The problem is I can't test this code beacause I dont know what to put instead of "sc" when i try to excute it.

Here is my code:

```
global class ExportContact implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O500000000000?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'asdf@asdf.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

    }
}
```

And my test code with my Error messsage :

```
@isTest 
global class ExportContactTest {
    @isTest static void TestSeizeHeure() {

        String sc = '0 0 16 * * ?';
        String test = ExportContact.execute('test', sc, new ExportContact());
    }
}
```

Can you give me an example of how to execute the code or why it dont work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unless you are trying to expose the ExportContact schedulable for use across a package boundary you don't need to use "global". You certainly don't need or want "global" access for a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call system.schedule

```
Test.startTest();
ExportContact test = new ExportContact ();
String sch = '0 0 16 * * ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('test', sch, test );
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: This won't work as expected in a unit test, at least not without considering Test.startTest and Test.stopTest.

Answer (score 0):

The SchedulableContext is an object, not a string. If your code under test doesn't even access the context's attributes and methods you can simply call the execute method with null. It would look like:

```
@IsTest
void testSomething() {
    new ExportContact().execute(null);

    ...
}
```

Note, however, that sending emails doesn't work in unit tests...

Comment: N.B. and, if code under test references the schedulableContext object, be sure to test for null. E.g. some schedulables abort themselves if they see some other job is still running